Dataset format/ prompt template for fine tuning Qwen 2.5-Coder Instruct
I see that codellama 7B Instruct has the following prompt template:
<s>[INST] <<SYS>>\n{context}\n<</SYS>>\n\n{question} [/INST] {answer} </s>

But I could not find what the prompt template should I use for Qwen 2.5-Coder 7B Instruct. I am really confused about this. I am planning to change the above prompt template to the below template for Qwen:
<|im_start|>[INST] <<SYS>>\n{context}\n<</SYS>>\n\n{question} [/INST] {answer} <|im_end|>

But I am not sure whether the above template is correct for Qwen and what about <<SYS>>, [INST] and [/INST] tokens.
Thank you

<|im_start|>system\nYou are a helpful assistant.<|im_end|>\n<|im_start|>user\nWhat is large language model.<|im_end|>\n<|im_start|>assistant\n

i think this is what you are looking for.
the <<SYS>>, [INST] and [/INST] tokens do not exist in their tokenizers. 1

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
